# How to save data from html to aspx and make it add data to the same file with each new user

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm new to asp.net and trying to make a questionnaire and style it in html module. I got data to save to aspx file through POST but it erases after I close the browser tab.
Here is the code I have:
HTML

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="/Portals/0/katya/formlist/simpleform.aspx" method="post">
            First name:<input type="text" name="fname" /><br />
            Last name:<input type="text" name="lname" /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

ASPX

```html
<%
response.write(request.form("fname"))
response.write(" " & request.form("lname"))
%>
```

So I'm trying to have data in the same file from every user who fills up the form but I can't seem to find the right info on how to do it. Looking forward to any suggestions. Thanks

Comment: You don't modify the ASPX. You generally store data in some sort of data store. This is often a relational database (SQL Server, SQLite, MySQL etc) but could be a non-relational database (MongoDB, RavenDB etc), in memory, or a JSON file, or some other web service.

Comment: Google has plenty of results for **C# WebForm Guestbook**.

Comment: Thank you so much I found this
 https://www.sitepoint.com/create-own-guestbook-asp-net/
and set it up so it's working now